# Why was "Isn't it obvious the pitch value alphabet language of music is Chomsky regular?" closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

The question [Isn't it obvious the pitch value alphabet language of music is Chomsky regular?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/133074/70803) seems like a valid and potentially useful music theory question. It asks about whether music can be modeled in a particular mathematical/linguistic way, which bears directly on subjects like music cognition and computer-based music creation and recognition. These general areas have been the subject of significant music theory study for at least a decade, and going back to at least to the 1940s.

It is closely related to [In what language-level in Chomsky's hierarchy would the chord-progressions of classical music be categorized?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/100177/70803), which received 12 upvotes to only one downvote, plus nine answers including one for 8 upvotes, one for six, and one that received a bounty.

IMO, the question should be reopened.

Comment: Right off the bat, anything that starts with “isn’t it obvious” doesn’t seem good to me. Why it’s not worded “is the pitch value alphabet language of music Chomsky regular?” is beyond me. That would be a much more inviting question. Beyond that, Tetsujin said it best: “it’s an essay, not a question”.

Answer (score 6):

As it stands, the question is very badly worded. There may be a core question in there that is on-topic and answerable, but the question would need a major overhaul edit to bring it up to a useful state for re-opening.

I notice commenters have suggested trying to clarify the question, so let's see if that happens.